# How Can I Create a Menu Of Three Buttons of Different Shape That Form a Menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, menu, android-studio-3.0

I want to be able to create a menu of three buttons like the one in this link in Android Studio
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easy.pedometer.step.counter.handle

Answer (score 0):

The 3 buttons in the third screen is called TabLayout.

Here is link to the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

Maybe, you find the ui a little bit different but you can customize.

Comment: how do you obtain the rounded edges of the buttons?

Comment: You can do a shape and set it like a tabBackground.

Here is an example of shape:
http://www.gadgetsaint.com/tips/rounded-corners-views-layouts-android/#.Xjl6Y5MzbOQ